# How to get Twig 1.5

Tags: installation, twig, dump

According to this page http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html
I need at least twig 1.5 to run the `{{ dump() }}` command.

I run the installation via composer with `composer require twig/twig:~1.0` according to this page to get the "latest version" http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html.

This gets me installed the version 1.18.2. How to get version 1.5 and more?

Comment: Just so you know 1.18.2 > 1.5. Version numbers are not decimals. It went 1.0, 1.1, ..., 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, ..., 1.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will help you.

[Basic usage - Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions)

If you want the 1.5 version you should use

`composer require twig/twig:1.5`

Other:
1.5 is smaller than 1.18
;)

Comment: Thanks. I asked because when I am dumping variables I have this error 'The function "dump" does not exist in "front_page.html.twig" and I supposed it was the twig version. Nevermind thanks. I'll open another question then.

Comment: "The dump function is not available by default. You must add the Twig_Extension_Debug extension explicitly when creating your Twig environment." - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

Comment: yeah I know I already set debug to true... but I still have the same problem. Thanks buddy